# Mysql Select parent products from table based on child title

Tags: mysql, select, parent-child

I have a products table with following data:

```
    ID  PARENT_ID   TITLE
    1   0       Elisa Dress
    2   1       Elisa Dress blue size XS
    3   1       Elisa Dress blue size M
    4   1       Elisa Dress blue size L
    5   1       Elisa Dress blue size XL
    6   1       Elisa Dress red size XS
    7   1       Elisa Dress red size M
    8   1       Elisa Dress red size L
    9   1       Elisa Dress red size XL
    10  0       Jennifer Dress
    11  10      Jennifer Dress yellow size XS
    12  10      Jennifer Dress yellow size M
    13  10      Jennifer Dress yellow size L
    14  10      Jennifer Dress yellow size XL
```

If the user seraches for "dress blue" and i run the query i get mutiple results (all childs) but i want to return just the parent. The Problem is that the parent doesn´t include the color. If I group i get unwanted result, i get a child element but not the parent.

Can someone please help.
Thank you

Comment: how many levels on the hierarchy can you have? just 2?

Comment: @PravinS if i use the condition PARENT_ID=0 it will return zero results.

Comment: @wxyz yes only 2 Levels

Comment: try this: select * from products p1 where parent_id = 0 and (title like &param or (select count(*) from products p2 where p2.parent_id = p1.id and title like &param)>0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how you are getting the current results or what your implementation looks like, but I would suggest taking a look at Closure Tables.

[Article On Closure Tables](https://coderwall.com/p/lixing)

Comment: if i want to use two tables i would separate child and parents table and get the wanted results using JOIN.
but it will be more complicated

Comment: Try joining the table with itself.

Something like:

SELECT DISTINCT t1.id FROM dresses t1
INNER JOIN dresses t2 ON t.id = t2.parent_id
WHERE t1.parent_id = 0

Comment: I quickly did a test, I've recreated your table and entered some of your data.  (My table's name is test).  This is the query:

SELECT DISTINCT t.id,t.title,t2.title FROM test t
INNER JOIN test t2 ON t.id = t2.parent_id
WHERE t.parent_id = 0 AND t2.title LIKE "%dress blue%"

And this is the results:

1 Elisa Dress Elisa Dress Blue
10 Jennifer Dress Jennifer Dress Blue

Is this what you are looking for? (Sorry I am trying to understand the problem :) )

Comment: sorry on the first try i used the wrong alias for the keyword search. u understood right. Thank you. Problem is now solved.